# Getting three inputs n for length of the input and k for the amount of digits to be deleted and output is the maximum amount possible, output is wrong

Tags: java

I'm trying to get two `int`s, at first, from the user:

- `n` being the length of the input which user will write
- `k` being the amount of digits to be deleted.

The output should be in a way that after deleting `k` amount of digits it should be the maximum amount possible.

Constraints:

```
0 < k < n <= 2000
```

For the most part it works but for example with these inputs it gives out a wrong output

```
n = 7
k = 3
num = 1239438
```

the output of this is 9438 while it should be 9843

This is the code:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        String num = sc.next();
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        if (num.length() < n || num.length() > n || 2000 < n || n < k || k == 0)
            System.out.println("Error!!!");
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                char c = num.charAt(i);
                System.out.println("log s: " + stack + " k: " + k);
                while (!stack.isEmpty() && k > 0 && stack.peek() < c) {
                    stack.pop();
                    k--;
                }
                stack.push(c);
            }
            System.out.println("log w: " + stack + " k: " + k);
            while (k > 0) {
                stack.pop();
                k--;
            }
            System.out.println("log f: " + stack + " k: " + k);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < stack.toArray().length; i++) {
                sb.append(stack.elementAt(i));
            }
            System.out.println("log p: " + stack);
            int ansNum = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
            int revNum = Integer.parseInt(sb.reverse().toString());
            System.out.println(Math.max(ansNum, revNum));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the *first* line that doesn't do what you expected for the case where the output is wrong?

Comment: How can the answer be supposed to be 9843? You can't get from 1239438 to 9843 by deleting digits.

Comment: I don't understand (from the example in your question) why the output should be 9843 (and not 9438). Can you [edit] your question and explain why?

Comment: One idea is to treat the input number as a `String` of individual digits.  Sort the `String` in descending digit order and remove the last K digits from the `String`.  By the way, you don't have to ask for N, because N = the length of num.

Comment: to have a bigger number you have to remove the lower digits and then sort the remaining descending. So, make a TreeSet of integers, remove the first until count is done and then add the remaining to a list, reverse the list and print.

Comment: BTW you should do your own homework